# Store a simple list server sided / difference to localstorage

Tags: php, html, css, mysql, database

I'd like to know how it is possible to save a simple list (`<ul><li></li></ul>`) server sided. I never did something like that. What I did is a localstorage.
Localstorage is pretty easy tho, as you can just add localStorage to what you want:

```
$('.myObject').css('color', localStorage.mySavedColor);
```

and call it in a function afterwards:

```
function saveColor() {
  localStorage.mySavedColor = true;
}
```

So, is server sided storage like the same? I guess it's a bit more complicated right? 
Precisely I try to save the list (created with javascript from a user input) on [this codepen](http://codepen.io/tobiasglaus/pen/xgBeaJ) server sided.

```
<div id="content">
  <section class="tabcontent">
    <ul class="plannerlist">
    </ul>
  </section>
  <section class="tabcontent">
    <ul class="plannerlist">
    </ul>  
  </section>
  <section class="tabcontent">
    <ul class="plannerlist">
    </ul>
  </section>
  <section class="tabcontent">
    <ul class="plannerlist">
    </ul>
  </section>
  <section class="tabcontent">
    <ul class="plannerlist">
    </ul>  
  </section>
  <section class="tabcontent">
    <ul class="plannerlist">
    </ul> 
  </section>
</div>
```

The javascript creates list items in specific `<ul>`'s, which I wanna save server sided.

Comment: How you do this depends entirely on the server language and type of database you're using. The question itself is also bordering on being too broad, unless you can show an attempt that you made yourself to achieve this

Comment: Ah didn't know you can do that with different languages. I thought like php should work. My database is mySQL

Answer (score 0):

> So, is server sided storage like the same?

No, it's not. There is no javascript built-in server side storage like localStorage that you mention.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is a program that runs in a client browser. If you want to save something server-side, you have to get a server and implement such feature.

It appears that your app will have more than one user.

This means:

- You have to distinguish one user from another probably with some sort of authorization. Keep in mind that most users tend to hate registration and confirming accounts by email.
- A better idea would be to save the text of Planner Events, rather than HTML tags with text. HTML tags carry little useful information to the user and open many vulnerabilities (think of saving an unescaped  tag instead of text).

What you are looking for is server-side scripting, which is vastly different from client-side scripting. Check out [W3S tutorial on PHP](https://www.w3schools.com/Php/) to get started.

**EDIT:** I recommend you to pick up a free shared hosting or build a webserver  locally on your PC. Check out WampServer or XAMPP for running server locally, or google any free php mysql webhosting.

Comment: @TobiasGlaus Great! Check out W3S tutorial on PHP to save data to MySQL and retrieve it.

Comment: Please don't recommend W3Schools as a resource. They are not, and never have been, affiliated with the W3C in anyway, yet continue to trade on their reputation. Their online diplomas would be an absolute joke if they didn't cost money. As it is they are a sham. Plus their articles are often outdated, and in some cases completely wrong. Try this instead: http://www.phptherightway.com/

Comment: @TobiasGlaus Alright, then go for phptherightway.com. If you need any help with code, PM me.

Comment: @WearyAdventurer Stupid question. But how do I PM someone on SO?